# New Drupal 8 install, homepage works, all other pages throwing a 404

Tags: installation

I have a server that houses my personal website (in the root folder.) Let's call it me.com. In the root I have: me.com files, a /dir/ called "me2." In /me2/ I have my drupal 8 install for a new site. Installed fine. Logged in, can access homepage. Every other link I click goes to a 404. I am not sure why this is happening.

*Edit: "me.com" site is Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that you don't have the .htaccess file on the root of your Drupal 8 website.

Comment: Do you have an example of the file? I tried a handful of things like adding "RewriteBase /me2/drupal" to the htaccess file. Again, the root of my site has a Wordpress installation so the .htaccess includes some code for that, although commenting all of that out didn't make a difference.

Comment: The .htaccess file comes included with Drupal. Perhaps just download a new Drupal instance and just upload the .htacess file.  When I ran into cases that only the home page was working, it was that I didn't have the .htaccess file (We usually don't commit .htaccess file in our repo).  I am not sure if you need to update the .htaccess of the Wordpress site(main site).

Comment: So I may be a complete idiot, but I'm not seeing a .htaccess file in Drupal 8's download zip. *Edit: I'm working locally so of course I can't see .htaccess ... opened the folder with Filezilla and WALA! There it is.. Thanks!

Comment: The .htaccess didn't get copied over because I dragged the site files from the Drupal install to my Transmit window. My mac doesn't see .htaccess so it wasn't selected and dragged. I feel like an idiot.